# Design for survey app

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to java and want to ask for a help about design. I'm going to build a simple survey app for android in java.

Here is how I see the app:

- The main page (*activity_main*) contain *LineEdit* for ID and two buttons: *Login* and *SignUp*. This activity *onCreate* loads all registered users and questions from DB.
- Sign up page (*activity_signup*) contains several *LineEdit* fields for user info as well as *SignUp* button. Also it provides free ID *onCreate*.
- Profile page (*activity_profile*) contains some user info (as *TextView*), possibly  and a *Survey* button.
- Survey page (*activity_survey*) contains *Question*, *Answers* and two buttons: *Prev* and *Next*.

Please mention if something might be improved.

**Questions:**

1. Should I store all users and questions as private field in `class MainActivity` or somewhere else? (Assume that DB is so small that it perfectly fits in RAM)
2. How can I modify the DB with newly created user from *activity_signup*? It is rather general question, like how can I access private fields from other activities preserving encapsulation?
3. I'd like to have a filed like `private static User current_user` in `class ProfileActivity`. But I can get the user only from DB, which is private field of `class MainActivity`. How can I pass the user from *activity_main* to *activity_profile* (again preserving encapsulation)?
4. *activity_survey* contain answers of different types, e.g. Yes/No; single/multiple choice (+ your variant) etc. How can I handle this in java? My idea is to create an abstract `class AbstractQuestion` with method `fillLayout` and inherit several `class ConcreteQuestion` (here concrete should be replace with an appropriate title) from it which contains implementation of certain type of question. Store all questions in array of `AbstracQuestion`'s. Is it doable in java or is there more right way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can use SQlite db or ORMLITE for this

Comment: @Nithinlal thanks for pointing out, but the question is more about java design rather than DB. Assume that DB is a static CSV file of 1 Mb size.

Comment: You can also use ORM Lite for this

Comment: Please try to limit your posts to one question - if the database is the immediately concern, then ask about that. The layout and design of your app is purely opinion based, and is something for you to ultimately  implement and decide

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't store such objects in Activity. You have several options for data persistence - these are listed here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html - of course that does not cover any "external" sources such as databases like Realm or Firebase but let's keep to the basics.

If your data is complex and you think that it would be easy for you to retrieve it using SQLite queries then the SQLite Database is the way to go. You can access it using ContentProvider which can be queried from any place where you have Context.

You can also store it locally on your internal or external storage with simple `Serializable` classes. Imagine a single object let's call it `Database` that is `Serializable` and that contains all the data you need. You could load it in your App startup (like in extended Application class) and store the reference so it won't get garbage collected. Then you can access it from a Application static method you could write to get the reference. It is probably the fastest way to implement a simple storage with fairly complex structure but that is probably not the best if your data is "big". It will increase your App start time (preferably make the load and save operations asynchronous).

If your data is simple you can use SharedPreferences to store "key-value" data. This is a little like second approach but using the Android framework to do it.

The option 2 and 3 require that your data is Serializable or Parcelable. As Android says that Parcelable should not be used for persistence but rather for communication let's skip that one.
You can either make you objects Serializable or translate them to json objects with i.e. Gson library. and store those serialized json objects. Making them serializable directly may be faster approach but sometimes keeping jsons makes more sense.

2. You can't and you shouldn't have to.
3. If you wan't to keep your data in static fields move them to extended `Application` class (make sure you point it in AndroidManifest.xml with specific xml parameter) and access it from there. You can get access to your `Application` class whenever you have `Context` via `context.getApplicationContext()` that you can cast to your custom class.

To tell Android to use your custom Application class use the following in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name=".YourAppClass"
    ...>

...
</application>
```

4. I am not sure if I get the 4th question right. Basically if you have multiple values you need to store your results in some collection i.e. ArrayList. Your whole questionare could be represented by a `Map<Question,List<Answer>>` then <- arbitrary class names (these could be enums too)